# iOS 15 Xcode 13 in app purchases not working

Tags: in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit, ios15, xcode13

I am testing applications on iOS 15 and iOS 14 devices. So on iOS 14 IAP working fine but on iOS 15 not working. Anyone, please help is this issue from the apple side?

update: working on the simulator but not on device

account type: Sandbox

Comment: I can't say why your iaps aren't working, but it shouldn't be a problem on apples side. Our iaps work flaw less on iOS 14 and 15.

Comment: @PaulSchröder working on simulator but not on device.

Comment: Same issue - simulator the purchase popup shows but not on device. No error thrown for me